# Some features listed in attribute table not visible on map in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, features

My vector layer is a track file with points every 2-3 seconds. When added they all appear in the attribute table but not on the map view. There doesn't seem to be a pattern or any attribute that distinguishes those that are shown from those that aren't.

I'm using QGIS version 3.4.3-Madeira.

Any suggestions where I could find a solution?

Comment: In attribute table you can mark a row and zoom to that feature on the map. QGIS will zoom to anything? I think it's either duplicates geometry or lack of geometry for that feature.

Comment: make the point symbol transparent to see if you have overlapping geometry

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your feedback and comments. Its highlighted where my problem is. The points have only got 4 decimal places which means many points are lying on top of each other. The resolution of the gps tracker doesn't allow for higher resolution. Of the 1821 points in the attribute table there are only 1127 unique points.